# require() of ES Module gulpfile.js not supported n gulp node js

Tags: node.js, gulp, nodes, gulp-watch

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';
const gulp = require("gulp");
const imagemin = require("gulp-imagemin");
const webp = require("imagemin-webp");
const extReplace = require("gulp-ext-replace");

gulp.task("exportWebP", function() {
  let src = "artists/**/*.jpg"; // Where your PNGs are coming from.
  let dest = "dist/images"; // Where your WebPs are going.

  return gulp.src(src)
    .pipe(imagemin([
      webp({
        quality: 75
      })
    ]))
    .pipe(extReplace(".webp"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest));
});
```

package.json

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "main": "gulpfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "gulp-ext-replace": "^0.3.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^8.0.0",
    "imagemin-webp": "^7.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2"
  }
}
```

here i run gulp js file it show the error

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module index.js from gulpfile.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
at Object. (gulpfile.js:3:18)
at async Promise.all (index 0) {
code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Many packages moved to esm modules and can no longer be imported using `require`

Change `require` to `import`

```
import gulp from "gulp";
import imagemin from "gulp-imagemin";
import webp from "imagemin-webp";
import extReplace from "gulp-ext-replace";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically import the imagmin package inside the function where you are using it.

for example let say before version 8, the function would look something like below:

```
function buildSprite() {
    return src(location.sprites.source + '*.svg')
        .pipe(imagemin.default([
            imagemin.svgo({
                plugins: [
                    {
                        removeViewBox: false,
                        collapseGroups: false
                    }
                ]
            })
        ]))
        .pipe(dest(location.sprites.dist));
}
```

after version 8 your function gonna look like below:

```
async function buildSprite() {
    const imagemin = await import('gulp-imagemin');
    return src(location.sprites.source + '*.svg')
        .pipe(imagemin.default([
            imagemin.svgo({
                plugins: [
                    {
                        removeViewBox: false,
                        collapseGroups: false
                    }
                ]
            })
        ]));
}
```