# Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module ...\angular\node_modules\globby\index.js from ...\angular\gulpfile.js not supported

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

My angular project was perfectly run but for some error I tried to reinstall Nodejs and npm and problems began. After that when I try to use command `npm start` in my angular project I faced this error:

> Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module D:...\angular\node_modules\globby\index.js from D:...\angular\gulpfile.js not supported.
> Instead change the require of index.js in D:...\angular\gulpfile.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
> at Object. (D:...\angular\gulpfile.js:4:14)
> at async Promise.all (index 0) {
> code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
> }

I didn't know if this reinstalling was my source of problem so I tried to move to my old version of Nodejs and npm but problem is still there.
current version of Nodejs and npm on my system:

> ```
> D:\...\angular>node -v 
> v17.7.0
>
> D:\...\angular>npm -v
> 7.19.1
> ```

I've read lots of same questions but answers didn't work for me.
for example I tried to use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74735744/5649590)  on my `gulpfile.js`

And here is my `gulpfile.js` file:

```js
var gulp = require("gulp");
var path = require('path');
var merge = require("merge-stream");
var globby = require('globby');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var less = require('gulp-less');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var cleanCss = require('gulp-clean-css');

var bundleConfig = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'bundles.json'));
var production = false;

var styleEntries = {};
var scriptEntries = {};

function processInputDefinition(input) {
  var result = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var url = input[i];
    if (url.startsWith('!')) {
      result.push('!' + path.resolve(__dirname, url.substring(1)));
    } else {
      result.push(path.resolve(__dirname, url));
    }
  }

  return result;
}

function fillScriptBundles() {
  // User defined bundles
  for (var k = 0; k < bundleConfig.scripts.length; k++) {
    var scriptBundle = bundleConfig.scripts[k];
    scriptEntries[scriptBundle.output] = globby.sync(processInputDefinition(scriptBundle.input), {
      noext: true
    });
  }
}

function fillStyleBundles() {
  // User defined styles
  for (var k = 0; k < bundleConfig.styles.length; k++) {
    var styleBundle = bundleConfig.styles[k];
    styleEntries[styleBundle.output] = globby.sync(processInputDefinition(styleBundle.input), {
      noext: true
    });
  }
}

function getFileNameFromPath(path) {
  return path.substring(path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
}

function getPathWithoutFileNameFromPath(path) {
  return path.substring(0, path.lastIndexOf('/'));
}

function createScriptBundles() {
  var tasks = [];
  for (var script in scriptEntries) {
    tasks.push(
      createScriptBundle(script)
    );
  }

  return tasks;
}

function createScriptBundle(script) {
  var bundleName = getFileNameFromPath(script);
  var bundlePath = getPathWithoutFileNameFromPath(script);

  var stream = gulp.src(scriptEntries[script]);

  if (production) {
    stream = stream
      .pipe(uglify());
  }

  return stream.pipe(concat(bundleName))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bundlePath));
}

function createStyleBundles() {
  var tasks = [];
  for (var style in styleEntries) {
    tasks.push(
      createStyleBundle(style)
    );
  }

  return tasks;
}

function createStyleBundle(style) {

  var bundleName = getFileNameFromPath(style);
  var bundlePath = getPathWithoutFileNameFromPath(style);

  var stream = gulp.src(styleEntries[style])
    .pipe(less({
      math: 'parens-division'
    }));

  if (production) {
    stream = stream.pipe(cleanCss());
  }

  return stream
    .pipe(concat(bundleName))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(bundlePath));
}

function build() {

  production = true;

  fillScriptBundles();
  fillStyleBundles();

  var scriptTasks = createScriptBundles();
  var styleTasks = createStyleBundles();

  return merge(scriptTasks.concat(styleTasks));
}

function buildDev() {

  fillScriptBundles();
  fillStyleBundles();

  var scriptTasks = createScriptBundles();
  var styleTasks = createStyleBundles();
  console.log("Dynamic bundles are being created.");
  return merge(scriptTasks.concat(styleTasks));
}

exports.build = build;
exports.buildDev = buildDev;
```

Comment: @noraj Hello, can you help me with this question, I saw your answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73059153/5649590) post, I thought you could help. thanks

Comment: @SNyamathi can you help me with this question, I saw your answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69968655/5649590) post, I thought you could help. thanks